# How can i keep the highest streak in a 0 - 1 random number generator c#

Tags: c#

I'd like to test out streak odds but i ran into a little bit of a pickle and excuse me in advance for the (most likely) ugly code.

So i'm creating a random number 0 - 1 where 1 = win and 0 = lose. 
i'd like to keep the highest streak of wins / loses. So when it loses it goes into an integer and if it wins the lose streak goes into a second integer and the first one becomes 0 again and i start my win streak where the same happens but for some reason with my current code it doesn't do what i want it to.
If i do this it says my win streak is 2 less than the entire amount of times it has won. Thanks for the help in advance and i'm sorry if my explanation is hard to understand (english is not my first language).

```
        Random rng1 = new Random();
        bool done = false;
        int win;
        int lose;
        win = 0;
        lose = 0;
        int lose1;
        int lose2;
        int win1;
        int win2;
        win1 = 0;
        win2 = 0;
        lose1 = 0;
        lose2 = 0;
        int roll1 = 0;
        while(done == false)
        {

            int roll = rng1.Next(0, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(roll);
            if(roll == 1)
            {
                win++;
                win1 = win;
                if(lose1 < lose2)
                {
                    lose2 = lose1;
                    lose1 = 0;

                }



            }
            else
            {

                lose++;
                lose1 = lose;

                if(win1 >= win2)
                {

                    win2 = win1;
                    win1 = 0;

                }

            }

            roll1++;
            if(roll1 == 100)
            {

                done = true;

            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("lose streak" + lose2 + " win streak" + win2 + " lose" + lose + " win" + win);
        Console.ReadKey();



    }
}
```

}

Comment: Simply add 2 to the result? ah, nvm, I guess I got it wrong

Comment: For a streak to calculate, you would need to store the previous value, because if they change, the streak is over

Comment: Statistically speaking, there is a chance to have a streak of 100 wins in a row, the same is for 100 losses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick. I created small arrays to keep track of all numbers. You can easely expand the example by having e.g.6 numbers (a dice). Only change 'possibilities'

```
using System;

namespace Gamble
{
    public class Dice
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                const int possiblities = 2;

                Random rng1 = new Random();
                int[] side = new int[possiblities];
                int[] maxSequences = new int[possiblities];

                int lastRoll = 0;
                int sequenceCount = 0;
                for (int rollCount = 0; rollCount < 100; rollCount++)
                {
                    int roll = rng1.Next(0, possiblities);
                    Console.WriteLine(roll);
                    if (lastRoll != roll)
                    {
                        if (maxSequences[lastRoll] < sequenceCount) maxSequences[lastRoll] = sequenceCount;
                        sequenceCount = 0;
                        lastRoll = roll;
                    }
                    sequenceCount++;

                    side[roll]++;

                }

                Console.WriteLine("lose streak:" + maxSequences[0] + " win streak:" + maxSequences[1] + " lose:" + side[0] + " win:" + side[1]);
                Console.ReadKey();

             }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code, while keeping it as close to yours as possible. Specifically, I just changed 2 lines. Honestly, I was just bored a bit, but either way, your question isn't really anyhow relevant to this website, you just had a logic flaw. Next time try to think about it for yourself, that's the only way to learn.

```
Random rng1 = new Random();
bool done = false;
int win;
int lose;
win = 0;
lose = 0;
int lose1;
int lose2;
int win1;
int win2;
win1 = 0;
win2 = 0;
lose1 = 0;
lose2 = 0;
int roll1 = 0;

while (done == false)
{
    int roll = rng1.Next(0, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(roll);
    if (roll == 1)
    {
        win++;
        win1++; // A change
        if (lose1 < lose2)
        {
            lose2 = lose1;
            lose1 = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lose++;
        lose1 = lose;

        if (win1 >= win2)
        {
            win2 = win1;
        }
        win1 = 0; // A change
    }

    roll1++;
    if (roll1 == 100)
    {
        done = true;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("lose streak" + lose2 + " win streak" + win2 + " lose" + lose + " win" + win);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Yeah i did try to think about it for a bit but i couldn't get the answer, and usually if i can't find something i google it and i come to this website, which is why i posted it here. Sorry if it doesn't belong here

Comment: I don't want you to feel discouraged, it's just that the main idea of the website is to provide answers that can relate to other people in the future. Particularly specific questions, like this one, aren't encouraged. Otherwise every person on earth could ask for help with their home work here. There're sure to be other websites which you can use for that reason. Again, don't feel bad, just try to restrain from doing so in future, regularly you would get your question heavily bombarded with minuses just in order to remove it from the list.

Comment: This wasn't for homework though, was genuinly just intrested in know this! but i'll remember and won't post this in the future :)